# How do I add a TabBarItem to a UITabBarController that creates a view over any other view that is currently shown in the TabBarController?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios8, xcode6

so in my App i have a UITabBarController with 4 tabs/views (1 - 2 - 3 - 4).
Basically, what i want to do is add a 5th TableBarItem in between those 4 existing 
TabBarItems(1 - 2 - HERE - 3 - 4).
The problem is, I would like my new TabBarItem to be more like a UIButton.
This means, if you klick it, it should bring up a transparent UIView or UIViewController over the UIViewController of the tab/item that is currently selected (1,2,3 or 4).

*For Example, if you selected tab/view 3 and then press the new item, it should slide in a half-transparent view over tab/view 3.*

*Another great example for this is the Tumblr app.*

My question is, how do i create a TableBarItem that doesn't refer to a ViewController, but creates a view over the ViewController that is currently on screen?

Comment: You could subclass UITabBarController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this using standard UITabbarController class. You can either subclass it and add this functionality or look for 3rd party component that already implements something like that.

Here is link for example: http://idevrecipes.com/2010/12/16/raised-center-tab-bar-button/